# Prevent canvas memory leaks and stutters

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, memory-leaks

I'm using a canvas to a display a grid composed by several interconnected dots (as seen in many other codepens\experiments) and it works just fine. To make the canvas responsive, I enclosed all of my code generating code in a function that is launched every time the viewport is resized. However, if I resize the viewport more than a few times, the canvas slows noticeably down and eventually stutters.

I have no clue about why, as i tried to prevent memory leaks by stopping the setInterval frame generating function and empty the arrays containing all the datas. Where am I doing it wrong?

I set up a JsFiddle that behaves just like the original website. Resizing the viewport rapidly decreases the performance:

http://jsfiddle.net/cr75n/1/

```
function initHomeBackground() {
    var generateFrameTimer;
    clearInterval(generateFrameTimer);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("stage");
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    var stage;
    var dots = [];
    dots.length = 0;
    var generateFrameTimer;
    var maxDistance = 100;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var dotsNumber = Math.round((((width * height) / 12000) + 60));
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    stage = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function dot(width, height, speed) {
        this.x = Math.round(Math.random() * width);
        this.y = Math.round(Math.random() * height);
        this.speedX = Math.round(Math.random() * speed - speed / 2);
        this.speedY = Math.round(Math.random() * speed - speed / 2);
    }

    function dotMatrix() {
        var generateFrame = function () {
            stage.fillStyle = "#fff";
            stage.rect(0, 0, width, height);
            stage.fill();
            stage.fillStyle = "#fff";
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].x += dots[i].speedX;
                dots[i].y += dots[i].speedY;

                if (dots[i].x < 0) {
                    dots[i].x = 0;
                    dots[i].speedX *= -1
                }
                if (dots[i].x > width) {
                    dots[i].x = width;
                    dots[i].speedX *= -1
                }
                if (dots[i].y < 0) {
                    dots[i].y = 0;
                    dots[i].speedY *= -1
                }
                if (dots[i].y > height) {
                    dots[i].y = height;
                    dots[i].speedY *= -1
                }

                stage.beginPath();
                stage.arc(dots[i].x, dots[i].y, 1.2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                stage.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0,0.25";
                stage.fill();
            }

            var lines = [];
            lines.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                for (var j = i + 1; j < dots.length; j++) {
                    var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dots[i].x - dots[j].x, 2) + Math.pow(dots[i].y - dots[j].y, 2));
                    if (dist <= maxDistance) lines.push([i, j, dist]);
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                stage.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, " + (((maxDistance - lines[i][2]) / maxDistance) / 6) + ")";
                stage.beginPath();
                stage.moveTo(dots[lines[i][0]].x, dots[lines[i][0]].y);
                stage.lineTo(dots[lines[i][1]].x, dots[lines[i][1]].y);
                stage.stroke();
            }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < dotsNumber; i++) {
            dots.push(new dot(width, height, 3));
        }

        generateFrameTimer = setInterval(generateFrame, 30);
    }
    var graph = new dotMatrix();
}


window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    initHomeBackground()
});
initHomeBackground();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the very two first lines : when you write :

```
function initHomeBackground() {
    var generateFrameTimer;
```

Then you just defined a generateFrameTimer variable which will be undefined. So next line :

```
clearInterval(generateFrameTimer);
```

necessarily does nothing.

On the other side, if you define the timer handle globally, and *not* in your init function :

```
 var generateFrameTimer ;
 function initHomeBackground() {       
          clearInterval(generateFrameTimer);
```

Then the generateFrameTimer var will 'remind' the interval value that you later set.

Just for the record, it would be easier to debug written like :

```
 // handle of the global animation
 var generateFrameTimer = null ;
 // ---------------------------------------
 // launch main animation
 function initHomeBackground() {
          // clear any previous instance
          if ( generateFrameTimer ) {   
                clearInterval(generateFrameTimer);
                generateFrameTimer = null ;
          }
```

And notice you can do few quick to do optimisation (code factorisation of all uses of dots[i] or line[j]) and it makes things a bit smoother :

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/cr75n/2/

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, i didn't solve this, but i found a decent workaround. Instead of relaunching the whole function, i simply resize the canvas. Note that i'm doing this only if the new viewport is bigger than the old one, or else many dots would be pushed to the sides of the canvas and glitch themselves.

```
responsiveCanvas = function() {
    updatedWidth = window.innerWidth;
    updatedHeight = window.innerHeight;
    if (updatedWidth > oldWidth) {width = window.innerWidth;canvas.width=width;}
    if (updatedHeight > oldHeight) {height = window.innerHeight;canvas.height=height;}  
};

window.addEventListener('resize', responsiveCanvas);
```